# bdf based pci-passthrough (non SRIOV) using OpenStack Liberty

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I am trying to get non SRIOV pci-passthrough using OpenStack Liberty, but not successful.

These are the steps followed

1. create pci_passthrough_whitelist in nova.conf of the compute node as pci_passthrough_whitelist = {"address": "0000:89:00.0", "physical_network": "test_phy_nw"}
2. As sriov is not used, do not add sriovnicswitch as mechanism driver
   in ml2. and do not do any ml2 sriov configurations. do not configure pci_passthrough_alias as alias does not support BDF (address)
3. create a neutron net - neutron net-create --name test_os_nw
   --provider:physical_network test_phy_nw --provider:physical_network_type flat. (is Flat ok ? or should i use vlan or vxlan type networks ?)
4. create port with direct vnic_type - neutron port-create 
   --name pci.port --binding:vnic_type direct
5. boot an instance with this port nova boot --flavor m1.small --image
   ubuntu --nic port-id=$(neutron port-show pci.port -F id -f value)
   test.vm

Two questions in this regard

1. Are the steps mentioned above correct & am i missing anything in the
   above steps ?
2. Is the process to achieve pci-passthrough (non SRIOV) different from
   SRIOV pci-passthrough ? If it is different, can you please share a
   link to it (or better can u give a quick summary of the process).

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimenting and reading, figured out BDF based pass through is supported only for SRIOV (as of Liberty).